# Upper bound for the sinc function

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

Show that there exists a constant $0<c<1$ such that
$$
   \frac{\sin x}{x} < c,\quad\textrm{for all }x\ge1.
$$

## --Context--

In Probability Theory Lévy's Theorem is crucial to uncover probability measures from certain functions which are obtained as limits of characteristic functions (Fourier transforms). The hard load of the work comes from Prokhorov's Theorem plus one key inequality involving the sinc function. In the 1-dimensional case it is enough to observe that ${\rm sinc}(x) \le \min(1,1/|x|)$. However, in the multivariate case a more accurate upper bound is needed, namely ${\rm sinc}(x) < c$ for some positive constant $c<1$.

It was in the middle of trying to adapt a proof of single-dimensional Lévy's Theorem to the multidiminsional case that I came across the need for this "detail". Since this function seemed related to the Laplace and Fourier transforms and I had found it in other contexts I decided to google it so to learn a little bit more. Here was where I learned how relevant this function is in e.g., Signal Processing (Kalman filters?). So I thought than instead of trying to proof the inequality myself it would be good to have it in SE so that others could start a "relationship" with this interesting function and its many properties. Obviously, I was plain wrong and I regret being so naïve.

Comment: It would help if someone could explain what's wrong with this question.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the insight. I've added some context. You guys should review your punishment policy or will keep discouraging people from participating here. In the end you will have the perfect site with 5 or 6 perfect subscribers.

Comment: Having your question closed is not a punishment. It's other users of the site telling you that your contribution needs improvement. You've responded well to that signal and improved things, so I'd say it's working. (As far as "ending up with 5 or 6 perfect subscribers", I think we're well past that point - and if someone would rather leave than produce posts of sufficient quality, I don't see any issues with that.)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, but I didn't improve anything. I just told my little story, which is not relevant. The real value remains in the sinc function, its upper bound and this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780744/269050).

Comment: In my opinion, great value is added by this story and background material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {\sin x} x \to \sin 1 <1$ as $x \to 1$. Hence there exists $r>0$ such that $1 \leq x \leq 1+r$ implies $\frac {\sin x} x <a$  where $a=\frac {1+\sin 1} 2$. Also $\frac {\sin x} x \leq \frac 1 {1+r}$ for $x \geq 1=r$. Can you finish?