# Showing that $\sin(\frac{x}{n}) \frac{n}{x} \leq 1$

Tags: calculus

I need to show that $\sin(\frac{x}{n}) \frac{n}{x} \leq 1$. I know that this is equivalent as showing that $\frac{\sin(a)}{a} \leq 1$ with $a = \frac{x}{n}$, however I don't know how to show this. If $|a| > 1$ this is easy, and I know the limit when $a$ tends to $0$, but how can I show that this is true for all $a$ with absolute value between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: I suggest you will take a look at the pictures in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1 , are they answering your question?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{{\sin x}}{x} = \int_0^1 {\cos (xt)dt} $.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication, that's a practice in programming, but this is a math forum. Use `a \cdot b` to get $a \cdot b$, `a \times b` to get $a \times b$ or simple juxtaposition, as you did in the body of the question.

Comment: @Gary Since $|\cos(xt)| \leq 1$ then $\int_0^1 \cos(xt) dt \leq \int_0^1 1dt = 1$ ?Anyway thanks for your comment ! Sorry, I didn't know that I could use $\LaTeX$ in the title.

Comment: @matyce Yes, that is correct, but put absolute value around the cosine inside the integral.

Comment: @Gary If I put the absolute value around the cosine then can I say that $|\frac{\sin x}{x}| =| \int_0^1 \cos (xt) dt | \leq \int_0^1 | \cos (xt)| dt \leq 1$ ?

Comment: @matyce Yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780744/269050.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The area of the triangle is $\frac 12 |\sin a|$  The area of the section of the circle is $\frac 12 |a|.$

$|\sin a| \le |a|$

Comment: Thanks, this visualization is really effective !